# Best practices handling large number of Strings from RSS feeds in Java and Lucene

Tags: java, string, rss, lucene

I have a situation where I have an hourly batch job which has to parse a large number of RSS feeds and extract the text of the title and description elements from each item per feed, into strings which will then have their word frequencies calculated by Lucene

But, not knowing how many feeds or items per feed, each string may potentially consist of thousands of words.

I suppose the basic pseudocode I'm look at is something like this:

```
for each feed
   for each item within date/time window
      get text from title element, concatenate it to title_string
      get text from description element, 
          concatenate it to description_string
          calculate top x keywords from title_string  

for each keyword y in x
   calculate frequency of keyword y in description_string
```

Can anyone suggest how to handle this data to reduce memory usage? That is apart from using StringBuilders as the data is read from each feed.

Though the contents of the feeds will be stored in a database, I want to calculate the word frequencies 'on the fly' to avoid all the IO necessary where each feed has its own database table.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't understand why you want to store text in database if you already have Lucene. Lucene is a **kind of database** with indexes built on words, not record id's, and that's the only difference for text documents. For example, you can store each item in the feed as a separate document with fields "title", "description", etc. If you need to store information about feed itself, create one more type of documents for feeds, generate id and put this id as a reference to all feed's items.

If you do this, you can count word frequency in a constant time (well, not real constant time, but approximately constant). Yeah, it will cause IO, but using databases to save text will do it too. And reading word frequency information is extremely fast: Lucene uses data structure, called **inverted index**, i.e. stores map of `word -> vector of < doc_number/frequency > pairs`. When searching, Lucene doesn't read documents itself, but instead reads indexes and retrieves such map - this is small enough to be read very quickly.

If storing text in Lucene index is not an option and you only need information about word frequency, use **in-memory index** to analyze each separate batch of feeds, save frequency information somewhere and erase index. Also, when adding fields to documents, set `store` parameter to `Field.Store.NO` to store only frequency information, but not field itself.

Comment: Thanks. But storing the data from the feeds in Lucene is not an option at present because of a business requirement that the this data be available from the database. So Lucene will only be used to calculate frequencies.

Comment: In this case you can use disk storage, but do not hold full text as I described in my answer for in-memory storage. You'll have access to all statistical information of feeds and, at the same time, you'll store full texts in database, i.e. fit your business requirements.

Comment: What I currently plan is to have Lucene use in-memory indexes to work out the frequencies of text in the title and description strings and store them in hash maps. Then using the most popular x number of keywords from the title hashmap, to get their frequencies from the description hashmap and use this as the frequency per keyword. The actual data of each feed is already in the database by this stage. But using Lucene to store frequencies is still an option because of other requirements to be addressed later. Thanks for advice.